# Java unicode fonts

Tags: java

I am developing a java game and I need characters, such as monsters and doors etc. I am trying to include them with the help of chars and unicode. However, some chars, such as a key, '\u26BF', do not show up properly in the terminal of the game, but rather as a box. Do I need to import some special fonts or how else would I solve this problem?

Comment: This is indeed a case for the font you use not supporting this particular glyph.

Comment: For example here `http://www.fontspace.com/unicode/char/26BF-squared-key` you can find fonts which contains the glyph you are looking for. But also have a look on the font lincense.

Comment: You mention a terminal.  Is the game itself a terminal based game?

Comment: Yes, I am using a swing terminal from Laterna.

Answer (score 2):

[GNU Unifont](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/gnu_unifont/index.htm) is reported as containing this Glyph. As it comes under the GNU public licence it is not subject to any licence fee.

Home page: http://unifoundry.com/unifont.html

It has TrueType, which should work wiht Java.

Answer (score 1):

Like people already pointed out in the comments sections, you will have to use another font containing those special characeters.

The font you are using seems to not support those characters, you can download any other font containing those character(s). The character 'u26BF' is a square box in some default fonts ([source](http://www.charbase.com/26bf-unicode-squared-key)).

You can find different fonts and even try them out on [DaFont](http://www.dafont.com/) and, like @SubOptimal warned you, check the licenses also before you download & use it.